# Crystal Report 9 Installation Hang on Window Server 2008

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to install crystal report 9 on my server 2008.
However the installation always hang and cannot proceed.
Just to check if crystal report is compatible with Window Server 2008 
or has anyone install crystal report 9 on WS 2008

please advices

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe CR 9 is not supprted on Server 2008

Comment: @AlecHenderson please check the link http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/boc/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/202ff507-281f-2b10-78b6-b6bce2668d6b?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&29665339128108

Comment: Do you need Crystal reports installed for development or just to run reports ? If you need to run reports you can install a viewer for 2008-2011 and use it to run CR 9 reports